# How to avoid new line in print function?

Tags: python, printing

In Python the `print` function automatically takes new line after the statements, if we want to print the whole statement in a single line then what should be used?

For example:

```
>>> for number in range(1,6):
...     for k in range (0,number):
...             print ("*")
...
```

I got the following output:

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*  
*
*
*
*
*
```

While I need this one:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma after print:

```
>>> for number in range(1,6):
       ...     for k in range (0,number):
       ...             print ("*"),
       ...     print()
```

Comment: It looks like the OP is using Python 3.x, in which `print` is a function.  Your solution is for Python 2.x.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following in Python 2.x.x. You could use `print "*"*i` where i is a number which prints '*' for  i number of times.

```
print "*" * 3
```

Output

```
***
```

All you have to do is to choose the value of `i` carefully.

```
for i in range(0,6): ## i increments through the range(0,6) for every iteration
    print "*"*i      ## "*" is printed 'i' times
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 6):

Set the [`end` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) of `print` to `""` and put an extra `print()` just outside the inner loop:

```
for number in range(1,6):
    for k in range (0,number):
        print ("*", end="")
    print()  # This is needed to break up the lines.
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> for number in range(1,6):
...     for k in range (0,number):
...         print ("*", end="")
...     print()
...
*
**
***
****
*****
>>>
```

Comment: This code could be simplified to `print(*("*"*n for n in range(1,6)), sep="\n")`

Comment: Also, `print ("*", end="\n" if k == number - 1 else "")`

Comment: @Thibaut, yes that works for this particular example

Comment: I tried to keep the code simple so as to not confuse the OP.  While the one-liner/compact solutions are nice for experienced Pythoners, I think they may be a little hard for the OP to grasp. ;)